# How do i change the value of "name" in my db with a code?

Tags: sql, replace

How do I replace this text "#I'll be back...™" which is the value of "name" in my database as you can see http://prntscr.com/7m01xz

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table name is "mytable" you would do:

```
UPDATE mytable SET name = 'new-value' WHERE name = '#I''ll be back...™'
```

You need to escape the single quote by using two single quotes.

Comment: But then I will change everything right? I just want to replace "#I'll be back...™" not replace everything, only those names.

Comment: You didn't say that before.  You need to escape a single quote with 2 single quotes.